# Complex Eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have complex eloquent relationship.

```
company
-id
-name

company_courts
-id
-company_id
-name

company_sports
-company_court_id
-sports_id

sports
-id
-name
```

Company can have many courts.
Courts can have many sports

I want to get all sports belonging to court in one company

I tried to solve this using hasManyThrough but did not work..

```
return $this->hasManyThrough(Sports::class,CompanyCourts::class,"","","id","id");
```

Comment: Which model did you add the `hasManyThrough` relationship to? Please can you show the relationship methods you have for all of the models mentioned in your question.

Comment: I feel obligated to ask how it "doesn't work"? What result are you currently getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query

```
Sport::whereHas('companySport', function($query) use ($yourCompanyId){
   $query->has('companyCourt'. function($q) use ($yourCompanyId){
      $q->has('company', function($q2) use ($yourCompanyId){
        $q2->where('company_id', $yourCompanyId)
      })
   })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has no native support for a direct relationship.

I've created a package for cases like this: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

```
class Company extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function sports()
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(
            Sports::class, [CompanyCourts::class, 'company_sports'],
            [null, 'company_court_id']
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try to use this.